# tf.get_variable initializer Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

How important is to choose the right value for the initializer in tensorflow?

With this code:

```
a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=0.1)
b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=-3.0)
```

[image]

with:

```
a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=0.1)
b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=0.0)
```

[image]

Why in the second example tensorflow doesn`t manage to fit the data properly? There is anything that can be done changing number_epochs or learning_rate?

This is my code:

```
# TensorFlow Model

# Config
num_epochs = 2000
learning_rate = 0.0001
# /Config

# Creating the graph
ops.reset_default_graph()

tf.disable_v2_behavior()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')

a = tf.get_variable('a', initializer=0.1)
b = tf.get_variable('b', initializer=-3.0)

h = a * X + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean( (h - Y)**2 )

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
    learning_rate=learning_rate
).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Running the Model
found_a = 0
found_b = 0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        _, costValue = sess.run(
            [optimizer, cost],
            feed_dict={
                X: x,
                Y: y,
            }
        )
        found_a = a.eval()
        found_b = b.eval()
        if epoch % (num_epochs/10) == 0: # Every 10 percent
            print("... epoch: " + str(epoch))
            print(f"cost[{str(costValue)}] / a[{str(a.eval())}] / b[{str(b.eval())}]")

# Seing the obtained values in a plot
xrange = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 2)

# Plot points
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')

# Plot resulting function
plt.plot(xrange, xrange * found_a + found_b, 'b')

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's hard to say with knowing the optimization method you're using, and the hyperparameters that you set. Please share your whole code.

Comment: Done added on the main question

Comment: For two variables and standard GD optimizer, a learning rate of 0.0001 is too low. You can easily make it around 0.01, and obtain similar results for either initialization.